# Which layout should I use?

Tags: android, android-layout

I have an image which is placed in the middle of the screen all around it i have textviews. My problem is that different devices will display the textviews farther/closer to the image. I need a view that will display textviews lets say 10dp away from my image. I tried with linearlayout, framelayout and relativelayout changing padding and margins but nothing works properly any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should always use RelativeLayout in your project, because its the most reliable of all, and will help in proper view in both landscape and portrait mode....

`RelativeLayout` is better and Use `toLeftOf` and `toRightOf`....

also `android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"`
     `android:layout_marginRight="10dp"`
     `android:layout_marginTop="10dp"`
     `android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"`

Comment: I totally forgot about android:layout_toRightOf and left.... silly me. Thanks!!!!